# Sublimetext 2.2 Highlight Matching Lines

Tags: editor, sublimetext2, sublimetext

I can't seem to find a package plugin or setting for highlighting matching LINES in Sublimetext 2.2?  If you highlight a single word it will circle all the other matching words, but I need that for the entire line.  See the attached image from EditPlus, that's what I need. You guys know of anything like this?  Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After selecting the line of interest, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> will select the next instance of the line.

If you wantto select all matching lines, use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd> (if on OSX, I think its <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f3</kbd> on windows).

No additional package is needed to find matching lines.

Comment: Duh, I knew about `alt+f3` all along.  I just always used it for matching single words.  Can't believe I never thought of using for more.  Thanks!